# Quadratic Distance

Tags: python, class, oop, point

I have a problem with a task. I need to write an python code which calculates a quadratic distance between two points.

The formula is:
D^2 = (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2

and my code:

```
def quadratic_distance(p1: Point, p2: Point) -> float:
# YOUR CODE HERE
class p1:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1):
        self.x = x1
        self.y = y1
class p2:
    def __init__(self, x2, y2):
        self.x = x2
        self.y = y2
result1 = p1.x - p2.x 
result2 = result1**2
result3 = p1.y - p2.y
result4 = result3**2
result5 = result2 + result4
return result5
```

but my problem is that i get an attribute error

`AttributeError: type object 'p1' has no attribute 'x'`

I am fairly new in the object oriented programming and have been stuck at this task. I hope someone can help me

```
assert quadratic_distance(Point(0, 0),Point(1, 1)) == 1.75
```

should be the solution

Comment: You overwrote the two Point parameters passed to your function with the two useless duplicate class definitions.  `Point` already *has* a definition somewhere (the caller of your function wouldn't have been able to create two instances to pass as parameters, otherwise), you don't need to repeat it yourself.

Comment: Oh i see. There was my problem. I was a little bit confused with p1 and p2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your formula, quadratic distance between Point(0,0) and Point(1,1) is 2. Not 1.75

This is my code. Try this

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


P1 = Point(0,0)
P2 = Point(1,1)

def quadratic_distance(p1: Point, p2: Point) -> float:
    result1 = p1.x - p2.x 
    result2 = result1**2
    result3 = p1.y - p2.y
    result4 = result3**2
    result5 = result2 + result4
    return result5

print(quadratic_distance(P1, P2))
```

Comment: You are right, the distance should be 2 not 1.75. Your code worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you have not created an object of the class. In python, x is not an attribute of a class but x is the attribute of its object.

So you can do it as:

```
class p1:
    def __init__(self, x1, y1):
        self.x = x1
        self.y = y1
class p2:
    def __init__(self, x2, y2):
        self.x = x2
        self.y = y2

p1_obj = p1(5,5)  
p2_obj = p2(10,10)   
result1 = p1_obj.x - p2_obj.x 
result2 = result1**2
result3 = p1_obj.y - p2_obj.y
result4 = result3**2
result5 = result2 + result4
return results
```

You can further improve it as p1 and p2 have the same properties (data member and member function) so we can just use one class named p (or any other name) and create two object p1 and p2 of the class

Answer (score 0):

Although you have declared the class p1 and p2 but you haven't created any object. So, you are getting this error.
x and y are the instances of class p1 and p2 you can't access by their class name.
Either define x and y as class variables inside the class or define a object each of class p1 and p2 like given below.
p1ob=p1(4,5)
p2ob=p2(5,6)